# Atomically update flag in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level

I am implementing a lightweight jobs system in my highly-concurrent application. For simplicity, I will be using Postgres to manage the state of all jobs in the system.

I have a table where processes can mark specific jobs as "running" via a boolean flag `is_running`. If multiple processes attempt to run the same job, only one of the processes should "win".

I want to have an atomic statement that the application processes will call in an attempt to exclusively mark the job as running.

```sql
UPDATE jobs SET is_running = true WHERE is_running = false AND id = 1
```

If there a is a single row with `(id=1, is_running=false)`, and multiple processes attempt to execute the above statement, is it possible for more than one process to actually set `is_running=true`?

I only want one of the processes to see an updated row count of `1` - all other processes should see an updated row count of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is safe and free from race conditions, because PostgreSQL will reevaluate the `WHERE` condition after it had to wait for a lock caused by a concurrent modification. It will then see the changed value and skip the row.